# Show that $E[X \mid \sigma (\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})] = E[X \mid \mathscr{G}]$ if $\mathscr{H}$ independent of $\sigma (\sigma (X),\mathscr{G})$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

The problem I'm working on is:

If $X \in L^1(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$, and $\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H}$ are $\sigma$ sub-algebras of $\mathscr{F}$, with $\mathscr{H}$ independent of $\sigma (\sigma (X),\mathscr{G})$, then show that $E[X \mid \sigma (\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})] = E[X \mid \mathscr{G}]$

Here is where I'm at:

Since $E[X \mid \sigma (\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})$ is the random variable in $L^2$ that is $\sigma(\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})$ measurable that minimizes $E[(X-Y)^2]$, and $E[X \mid \mathscr{G}]$ is the random variable in $L^2$ that is $\mathscr{G}$ measurable and minimizes $E[(X-Y)^2]$, I believe what I need to do here is show that for any random variable $Y$ that is $\sigma (\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})$ measurable that minimizes $E[(X-Y)^2]$, it is also $\mathscr{G}$ measurable. This would show  $E[X \mid \sigma (\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})] \geq E[X \mid \mathscr{G}]$, and $\leq$ I think follows easily since any thing that is $\mathscr{G}$ measurable is certainly $\sigma (\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})$ measurable.

I'm not sure how to show this, or if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that a $\mathcal{E}$-measurable $L^2$-integrable random variable $Y$ equals $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{E})$ if, and only if,

$$\int_{D} X \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_D Y \, d\mathbb{P} \tag{1}$$

for all $D \in \mathcal{D}$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is a $\cap$-stable generator of  the sub-algebra $\mathcal{E}$.

---

Here, we set

$$\mathcal{E} := \sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}) \qquad \mathcal{D} := \{G \cap H; G \in \mathcal{G}, H \in \mathcal{H}\}.$$

First of all, we note that $\mathcal{D}$ is in fact a $\cap$-stable generator of $\mathcal{E}=\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})$. Moreover, we have due to the independence of $\mathcal{H}$ and $\sigma(\sigma(X),\mathcal{G})$:

$$\begin{align*} \int_{G \cap H} \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}) \, d\mathbb{P} &= \int 1_H \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(1_G X \mid \mathcal{G})}_{\sigma(\sigma(X),\mathcal{G})-\text{measurable}} \, d\mathbb{P} \\ &= \int 1_H \, d\mathbb{P} \cdot \int 1_G \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}) \, d\mathbb{P} \\ &= \int 1_H \, d\mathbb{P} \int_G X \, d\mathbb{P} \\ &= \int 1_H \, d\mathbb{P} \int_G X \, d\mathbb{P} \\ &= \int 1_G 1_H X \, d\mathbb{P}.\end{align*}$$

This shows that $(1)$ holds for any $D=G \cap H \in \mathcal{D}$. Consequently, the claim follows.

Comment: Thank you, but there are some things I don't understand.  Isn't $Y = E(X|\mathscr{E})$ if and only if the integrals are equal for any $D \in \mathscr{E}$? I'm also not sure what a $\cap$ stable generator is. I'm also not sure if you're answering my original question, or helping me see how to use the approach I was trying. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: @David It suffices to have the equality for a $\cap$-stable generator of the sigma-algebra ($\cap$-stable generator means that $\sigma(\mathcal{D}) = \mathcal{E}$ and $D_1,D_2 \in \mathcal{D} \Rightarrow D_1 \cap D_2 \in \mathcal{D}$.) I answered your original question, because this approach is much more easier (at least if one knows this characterization of conditional expectation...)

Comment: Could you spell it out a little more for me? I'm still learning all of this stuff.  I was wondering about $D$, if we knew such a thing existed...but I suppose we could just take the $\mathscr{E}$ to be a trivial $\cap$ stable generator...Are you saying $D$ in this case will end up being $\mathscr{G}$? I don't see how the independence of $\mathscr{H}$ is coming in the picture either.  Thanks again.

Comment: @David I have added some more lines. Don't hesitate to ask if you don't get along with it; I simply don't want to write down all the details.

Comment: Thank you.  My $Y$ then is $E(X|\mathscr{G})$ and I want to show this is equal to $E(X|\sigma(\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H}))$. Is that right?

Comment: @David Yes. (Sorry, there were some typos - just corrected them.)

Comment: Okay, I see most of this now.  I'm having some trouble proving (1) though.  If I know something about a generating set of $\sigma(\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})$, in this case $D$...I don't see how to translate that into a statement about the entire $\sigma$ field. Now you said, "Recall that..." so I'm assuming this must be a well-known result...is it easy to explain, or can you direct me somewhere?

Comment: @David Do you know the following theorem on uniqueness of measures? Let $\mu,\nu$ be two finite measures on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and $\mathcal{D}$ a $\cap$-stable generator of $\mathcal{F}$. If $$\mu(D)= \nu(D)$$ for all $D \in \mathcal{D}$, then $$\mu(F) = \nu(F)$$ for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: No, I see that is what I need to show though.  To prove that, I would need to show that any element in $F$ can be written easily in terms of $D$, wouldn't I? I know one can't do that in general...is being $\cap$-stable sufficient to show this? I've never heard of $\cap$-stable before this answer...so is that the benefit?

Comment: Ah! I've got it, thank you.  I just realized what you're calling $\cap$ stable, I call a $\pi$-system.  Thanks!!